# Delete Files After Filename - vbscript

Tags: vbscript

Basically I am trying to write a script to delete files after a certain filename, so based on the below file list

```
FILE_000001_FULL.ZIP
FILE_000002_FULL.ZIP
FILE_000003_FULL.ZIP
FILE_000004_FULL.ZIP
FILE_000005_FULL.ZIP
FILE_000006_DELTA.ZIP
FILE_000007_DELTA.ZIP
FILE_000008_FULL.ZIP
```

Everything up until FILE_000005_FULL.ZIP would be deleted. The files are created using a tool and will be sorted by file name, so highest number first. Basically need the 2 latest FULL files kept and the DELTA's (if any) between them. I hope that makes sense.

So far, this is what I have, but just loops constantly, not just until it finds the 2 latest fulls.

```
Dim fso, folder, files, ToDel, sfolder
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
sFolder = ("C:\MDS")
Set ToDel = fso.CreateTextFile ("C:\MDS\FileList.txt", True)
Set folder = fso.GetFolder(sFolder)
set files = folder.files


For each folderIDX In files
    ToDel.WriteLine(folderidx.Name)
Next

ToDel.close


Dim arrFileLines()
i = 0
Set ObjFile = FSO.OpenTextFile("C:\MDS\FileList.txt", 1)
Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
    Redim Preserve arrFileLines(i)
    arrFileLines(i) = objFile.ReadLine
    i = i + 1
Loop

ObjFile.Close
s = 0

Do While s < 2
For l = Ubound(arrFileLines) to LBound(arrFileLines) Step -1
    For Each strLine in arrFileLines
        IF InStr(strLine, "FULL") <> 0 Then
        wscript.echo "Found Full!!!!"
        wscript.echo strLine, s
        s = S + 1
        End If

Next
Next
LooP
```

My thoughts was to delete the lines from the text file, then use this text file to delete the files from the directory.

Hopefully that all makes sense and someone can pass some advice on!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do this with two iterations through your folder and without the need/use of a text file. During the first pass, record the numbers assigned to the two latest FULL's. Then, in your second pass, delete any files that are less than your second-highest FULL.

Here's how it might look:

```
' First pass: Find the two latest FULLs...
For Each File In FSO.GetFolder("c:\mds").Files

    ' Is this a FULL?
    If Right(File.Name, 8) = "FULL.ZIP" Then

        ' Get the numeric value from the file name (6 digits starting as pos 6)...
        intNum = CLng(Mid(File.Name, 6, 6))

        ' Maintain the two latest FULLs...
        If intNum > intMax1 Then
            intMax2 = intMax1
            intMax1 = intNum
        ElseIf intNum > intMax2 Then
            intMax2 = intNum
        End If

    End If

Next

' Second pass: Delete anything prior to the second-latest FULL...
For Each File In FSO.GetFolder("c:\mds").Files

    intNum = CLng(Mid(File.Name, 6, 6))
    If intNum < intMax2 Then File.Delete

Next
```

Comment: That looks good, but seems to error on the 2nd command of intNum = CLng(Mid(File.Name, 6, 6)) on Line 28 Char 5. Error is type mismatch: Clng.

Comment: To keep things simple, I didn't do any error-checking here. You may have a file in your folder that isn't named like the others and, therefore, doesn't have a numeric value from chars 6 to 11 in its filename. Ensure all of your files are named according to your spec (`FILE_######_FULL/DELTA.ZIP`) and add some error-checking. For example, test that it starts with "`FILE_`" and ends with "`.ZIP`". Extract chars 6-11 as a string and test that string with `IsNumeric()` before converting to a number with `CLng()`. If you need help with any of that, just let me know.

Comment: Seems like the script is just not running, put a wscript.echo intNum command after the initial intNum command and the script runs but does not put anything out? Do any more variables need declared?

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim intNum, intMax2, intMax1

Comment: Do you have `On Error Resume Next` declared? If you do, disable it, and it should tell you if you haven't declared any variables (assuming you also have `Option Explicit` declared).

Comment: Bond, sorry to keep asking, but trying to get my head around this. The script reads through the files, but the IF statement doesn't seem to execute. Tried putting wscript.echo commands in at each point and it does not put any output. Even changed the Right(File.Name, 8) to Right(Lcase(File.name), 8) as read this could cause issues. Any Ideas?

Comment: Did you see my previous comment? Do you have `On Error Resume Next` anywhere in your code?

Comment: Sorry, yes I seen that and No I removed that.

Comment: So if you just do a basic file loop you don't see any files? Line1 = `For Each File In FSO.GetFolder("c:\mds").Files`, Line2 = `MsgBox File.Name`, Line3 = `Next`

Comment: All the file names are output and are correct. It does not seem to execute the IF statement    If Right(File.Name, 8) = "FULL.ZIP" Then.

Comment: Are you sure the statement isn't being _executed_ or is the expression just returning `False`? The way it's written, it will do a case-sensitive comparison. If your filename ends with `full.zip` or `FULL.zip` or `full.ZIP`, for example, the test will fail. To do a case _insenstive_ comparison, you can use `If UCase(Right(File.Name, 8)) = "FULL.ZIP" Then` or you can use the `StrComp()` function with the `vbTextCompare` option.

Comment: It was my fault, the .zip was lowercase. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: No problem. I should have been clearer in my example. Glad you got it working!